# How to just initialize the record without trigger "validateline" function in SuiteScript?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

There are 2 fields in the Invoice record of NetSuite.

One is the **poUnitCost** field, the other is the **poTotalCost**" field.

The value of **poTotalCost** equals **poUnitCost** multiply **quantity**.

**(*Formula: poTotalCost = poUnitCost x quantity*)**

Once the record is been creating, the script will call the pageInit which find the corresponding fields and fill them into the Invoice record.

However, script not only triggers the pageInit function but also the validateLine function.

How to just trigger the pageInit when creating the record without triggering the validate function?

The code is as the following:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/currentRecord', 'N/record', 'N/search'],
    function (currentRecord, record, search) {

        function pageInit(context) {
            console.log('inside pageinit function');

            var rec = context.currentRecord;
            var createdFromID = rec.getValue({
                fieldId: 'createdfrom'
            });
            var so_record = record.load({
                type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                id: createdFromID
                // isDynamic: true
            });

            var inv_lines = rec.getLineCount({
                sublistId: 'item'
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < inv_lines; i++) {
                var soLineID = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'so_line_id_in_Inv',
                    line: i
                });

                // Find the index of line whose 'custcol_so_line_id' field is soLineIDINV
                var soLineNumber = so_record.findSublistLineWithValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'so_line_id_in_SO',
                    value: soLineID
                });

                var poUnitCost = so_record.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'unit_cost_in_SO',
                    line: soLineNumber
                });

                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'unit_cost_in_Inv',
                    value: poUnitCost,
                    line: i
                    // fireSlavingSync: true
                });

                var lineQty = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'quantity',
                    line: i
                });

                var poTotalCost = lineQty * poUnitCost;

                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'total_cost_in_Inv',
                    value: poTotalCost,
                    line: i
                    // fireSlavingSync: true
                });
            }
            return true;
        }

        function validateLine(context) {
            console.log('inside validateLine function');

            var rec = context.currentRecord;
            var sublistName = context.sublistId;

            if (sublistName == 'item') {
                var poUnitCost = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'unit_cost_in_Inv',
                });

                var lineQty = rec.getCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'quantity',
                });

                var poTotalCost = lineQty * poUnitCost;

                rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                    fieldId: 'total_cost_in_Inv',
                    value: poTotalCost
                    // fireSlavingSync: true
                });
            }
            return true;
        }

        return {
            pageInit: pageInit,
            validateLine: validateLine
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop the sublist events from triggering. When a line is committed, `validateLine` will fire. You will need to adjust your `validateLine` handler to return `true` in any situations where you don't want it to execute its normal logic.

Comment: Hi erictgrubaugh, I added the "return" statement for each entry point function, could you suggest how to avoid triggering validateLine function while executing pageInit function? Thanks!

Comment: You can't avoid triggering it, so you just need to make sure that your handler is smart enough to not do anything when it doesn't need to.

Comment: Finally, I declare a global flag to tell if process is in pageInit function currently. While process run into validateLine function, if the flag is true, the validate function will be sikpped.